# How can I replicate NavigatorIOS component behavior with Navigator Component in react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Is is possible to make `Navigator` component behave similar to `NavigatorIOS` component ? If so which I think is certainly possible, what is the relevant code to do so ?

[image: Navigator]

[image: NavigatorIOS]

Answer (score 0):

What counts as `behaving similar to NavigatorIOS`? You can try checking out [react-native-router](https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router) and see if it's something that would help you. If you do want to try it, you'd have to go to [this PR](https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router/pull/54) and use those fixes, because the owner of the module hasn't updated in a while.